# How do i add a textview ontop of a picture

Tags: java, android

UPDATE: so i got the picture as a layout:http://gyazo.com/38a4c80dab36e15593a32f35951b9f7d 
Now how do i make it so that i can put text on the picture. I want to make sure that the text doesnt go beyond the picture box. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry!, i want to know how would i approach this problem!

Comment: you want to write over picture or want text over imageview in layout

Comment: How would i then make sure the text doesnt go beyond the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `RelativeLayout` where your picture is now. I suppose your picture has a fixed size (e.g. 60dp wide and 60dp high). Use that size for your RelativeLayout. Now add an `ImageView` as first child with both width and height set to `match_parent`. This ImageView will contain your picture. Add a `TextView` as second child, also with width and height set to `match_parent`. Now you have a TextView on top of an ImageView, both with the same size.